# Create a pivot table from external source

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, pivot-table, win32com

I'm using win32com to create a pivot table and I want to ask if it was possible to create one from an external data source. My data will be loaded from a hive database and I want to directly use that as my data without first storing it to a workbook and use it. If it will be also easy to load it into a pandas dataframe and use that, it will be good. But I'm not sure how to go about it. I know the data has to be sequences of sequences but mine won't work. Below is part of my code for testing this option with pandas and the error I'm getting

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
import win32com as win32
#Class to create pivot tables 
class CreatePivotTables(object):
    """
    A class that creates pivot tables given the correct parameters
    """
    def __init__(self, properties) -> None:
        
        # create Excel application object
        self.excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.excel.Visible = True

        # If we want to save only the pivot table to a separate work book, We will tweak the code and add
        # excel2 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        # excel2.Visible = True

        # # Create a new workbook
        # workbook = excel2.Workbooks.Add()

        # # Rename the first sheet as "pivot_table"
        # self.pivot_table_sheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
        # self.pivot_table_sheet.Name = "pivot_table"

        df = pd.DataFrame({
                        'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
                        'Age': [25, 30, 35],
                        'Salary': [50000, 60000, 70000]
                        })
        data = df.to_records().tolist()

        # open workbook
        self.properties = properties
        self.work_book = self.excel.Workbooks.Open(self.properties.input_path)

        # get sheet object
        # self.data_sheet = self.work_book.Sheets('Sheet1')

        self.work_book.Sheets.Add().Name = self.properties.pt_worksheet_name
        self.pivot_table_sheet = self.work_book.Sheets(self.properties.pt_worksheet_name)
        self.pt_location = len(self.properties.pivot_table_filters) + 10
    
        # grab the pivot table source data
        PivotCache = self.work_book.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=2, #xlExternal
                                                        SourceData=data)
        print(PivotCache)
        # create the pivot table object
        self.PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=f'{self.properties.pt_worksheet_name}!R{self.pt_location}C1',
                                                        TableName=self.properties.pivot_table_name)

        # selecte the pivot table work sheet and location to create the pivot table
        self.pivot_table_sheet.Activate()
        self.pivot_table_sheet.Cells(self.pt_location, 1).Select()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\pt_test.py", line 350, in <module>
    piovt_table = CreatePivotTables(pt_properties)
  File ".\pt_test.py", line 189, in __init__
    SourceData=data)
  File "C:\Users\Sorin\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 31019, in Create
    , SourceData, Version)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: According to docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create , the Create call will expect an object of type `WorkbookConnection` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection if you specify `xlExternal`. You are not passing that. Might be worth trying to establish a database connection direct to your database (if Excel has an adapter for it).

Comment: @DS_London i see. Thank you. That might be my only way of going about it. I'll try this and see how it goes